# Update CSV to a mysqldb Ignoring the IDs which has no entries

Tags: mysql, sql, python-2.7, phpmyadmin

I'm new to work on mysqlDB.

I have a table that looks like

```
id,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
```

Now,I have `CSV` file with approximately 11000 entries which look like

```
1,
2,Q,R,X,Y,Z
3,X,Y,Z
4,Q,R
100,R,X
5000,X,Q
200,
7000,
10000,
.....
```

My question is,How do i import the `CSV` to update the data only to the table column `H` where by ignoring the `ID` which has no entries present ? Any advice on this would be really great.

Expected Query Result for the Column `H`

```
ID           H
1
2         Q,R,X,Y,Z
3         X,Y,Z
4         Q,R
100       R,X
5000      X,Q
200
7000
10000
.....
```

Comment: How many columns does the csv have? Do they all go in the H column in the table?

Comment: @Vatev Yes,Buddy ! i have only two columns in CSV for Example A&B where A has ID and B might have multiple values in a cell !

Comment: Well there aren't any quotes or escapes there, any csv parser will interpret those as separate cells.